# Get different columns by joining two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Problem: I am trying to join `table1` and `table2` to get the `wk_nmbr` for `begin_date` and `end_date`. To distinguish, I am appending the word "begin" and "end" at the end of "wk_nmbr"

**table1**

```
begin_date,
end_date
```

**table2**

```
cal_date,
wk_nmbr
```

**Condition:**

```
table1.begin_date = table2.cal_date and
table1.end_date = table2.cal_date
```

Expected result in output:

```
begin_date,
wk_nmbr_begin,
end_date,
wk_nmbr_end,
```

Comment: Mona your question was clear, can you give some sample date from your tables, and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple query using an alias.

```
select begin_date, w1.wk_number as wk_nmbr_begin,
    end_date, w2.wk_number as wk_nmbr_end
from table1
join table2 as w1 on w1.cal_date=table1.begin_date
join table2 as w2 on w2.cal_date=table1.end_date
```